# Drupal Docker Setup

Tags: 8

I currently have a codebase for Drupal using Drupal-VM vagrant box and VirtualBox. I would like to migrate to docker but I am unaware on how to integrate it with my existing code base.

Can anyone help me? I have followed instructions from [Docker Hub - Drupal Install Steps](https://hub.docker.com/_/drupal) and [MySQL and Drupal Container](https://www.mikestiv.com/blog/running-drupal-docker) to spin up mysql and Drupal images but how do I make it point to my pre-existing codebase?

---

Previous posts with more details, questions and background:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65147301/migrate-drupal-local-environment-to-docker-container
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65129883/drupal-local-development-setup-environment

Comment: You talking about loval dev environment right? Then go for DDEV, Lando or Docksal. Don't reinvent the wheel. All you maybe need to worry about is the database. But I'd say get one from prod and import locally.

Comment: @leymannx Currently the database gets built with blt setup, and all the fields and tables are dropped and recreated there. How can i get that to be rebuilt?

Comment: @leymannx I have an issue that I documented here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65206503/services-cant-start-due-to-no-route-to-host and look at the comments I left on Patrick Kenny's answer

Answer (score 1):

You can mount host volumes, such as your application codebase, inside your container.

e.g with [`docker-compose`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/):

```
drupal:
  volumes:
    # Mount application codebase
    # - ./project-directory:/container-directory
    - ./project/dir:/var/www/docroot
```

You can also mount a host volume for your mysql data, to preserve the DB across docker stack rebuild.

```
mysql:
  volumes:
    # Database on host
    # - /host-directory:/container-directory
    - /var/lib/my-project/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
```

Comment: my site is built with composer and blt. How can I re-create all the tables and fields from all the yml files that are in my config/default?

Comment: @B.Cratty – `drush cim`?

Comment: @B.Cratty you can import the config as part of the install process ( https://www.drupal.org/node/2897299 ) . It's also possible to restore a DB export, e.g by mounting a folder with the SQL dump and import with `drush sqlc < export.sql`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in [lando](https://docs.lando.dev/basics/basics.html).

Basically, this is the workflow:

- Configure your `lando.yml` to get your site running locally and commit this to your repository.  This will allow everybody to create a local dev environment as long as they have cloned the repo and have lando installed.
- Use lando to run the site locally, and continue to commit code/build your project in the same way that you were doing before.

Here are [some notes from Acquia on setting up lando with BLT](https://support.acquia.com/hc/en-us/articles/360047166273-Configuring-Acquia-BLT-with-Lando).

Comment: I just ran through all the steps, and I'm having issues with the blt setup. It keeps failing with the Drupal installation. It gives me a warning  [warning] Failed to drop or create the database. Do it yourself before installing. dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/mysql
  Reason: image not found
sh: line 1: 71580 Abort trap: 6           mysql --defaults-file=/private/tmp/drush_jEVO19 --database=information_schema --host=localhost --port=3306 --silent -A < /private/tmp/drush_Xugn6U

Comment: Then it says  [info] Undefined index: value install.core.inc:2303
 [info] Array to string conversion install.core.inc:2303

In install.core.inc line 2307:
                                                        
  [Drupal\Core\Installer\Exception\InstallerException]  
  Database settings:                                    
                                                        
  Array